# SQL Where Clause - Way to Abbreviate Code for Multiple Dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a where clause that's pretty basic - it's meant to pick up loans that on the most recent processing day hit 42 days past due as compared to the prior processing day. I've since found out that I need to pick up loans that hit 175 days past due BUT also loans that hit an additional 175 days past due or 350 (175 x 2), 525, 700 etc...  This is the section of my current where clause with three of the date intervals, but literally, it should go beyond that (at 175 date intervals), but before keying all those additional 175 day increments, I was thinking there had to be a more succinct way of specifying at least several increments of 175 days beyond 350:

```
  Where
  ( 
     (ISNULL(li.PDDAYSREG,0) >= 42  
  and ISNULL(ld.PDDAYSREG,0) <  42) 
  or 
     (ISNULL(li.PDDAYSREG,0) >= 175
  and ISNULL(ld.PDDAYSREG,0) <  175)
  or 
     (ISNULL(li.PDDAYSREG,0) >= 350
  and ISNULL(ld.PDDAYSREG,0) <  350)
  )
```

Would greatly appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Windows Server 2012 R2 and the "li" is for the last processing day's value while the "ld" is for the prior processing day so it does return rows.  Sorry as I should have stated that more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you just do something like this?

```
where PDDAYSREG = 42 or
      (PDDAYSREG % 175 = 0 and PDDAYSREG > 0)
```

Most databases support `mod()` either as a function or using the `%` operator.

If the value is not an integer, I would suggest converting it to one rather than using ranges:

```
where cast(PDDAYSREG as int) = 42 or
      (cast(PDDAYSREG as int) % 175 = 0 and PDDAYSREG > 0)
```

Comment: This is interesting, Gordon Linoff.  I'm writing the where clause in Management Studio, and it is giving me an error: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 79
'mod' is not a recognized built-in function name.  But if it worked, would this give every 175 day increment beyond 175, ie, 350, 525, etc.?  The first line of code you offer does work without the "or..."

Comment: Gordon Linoff, the number's an integer, so using your first example but replacing mod (not available in t-sql) with % for:  li.PDDAYSREG = 42 or
      (%(li.PDDAYSREG, 175) = 0 and li.PDDAYSREG > 0) gives me the following error message: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 70
Incorrect syntax near '('.  I've tried every variation of ()s, I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: So @GordonLinoff, the syntax that seems to "work" using % in t-sql is: li.PDDAYSREG = 42 or
  ((li.PDDAYSREG % 175) = 0 and li.PDDAYSREG > 0) but I'm not sure this solves my original requirement of getting ALL  increments of 175, ie, 350, 525....  Thanks so much for your insight!